# Выводит не всю строку

Tags: java, android, криптография

Здравствуйте, данный код шифрует и дешифрует строку. Проблема в том что когда я вывожу в text view дешифрованную строку, выводится только последняя буква. Логика подсказывает что надо что то сделать с циклом, но что?

```
private void main(String[] args)throws LoginException, NoSuchPaddingException,
             NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeyException, BadPaddingException,
             IllegalBlockSizeException {

   String s = "ab";
   Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");

   KeyGenerator kgen = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");
   kgen.init(128);
   SecretKey key = kgen.generateKey();

   cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE,key);
   byte[] bytes = cipher.doFinal(s.getBytes());
   for (byte b : bytes){
      //  time.setText(s+" "+ b);

   }
   //  String str = new String(bytes, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
   Cipher decript = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
   decript.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE,key);
   byte[] decriptedBytes = decript.doFinal(bytes);
   for (byte b : decriptedBytes){
      time.setText(String.valueOf((char) b));
   }
}
```

Comment: `time.setText(time.getText() + String.valueOf((char) b));`

Answer (score 1):

Коллеги *почти* все верно расписали, но в коде есть пара проблем, а именно используется:

```
Cipher.getInstance("AES")
```

По умолчанию в этом случае используется мода сцепления блоков `ECB`, в переводе на русский означает, что шифрованные блоки не перемешиваются, а просто тупо конкатенируются, что может приводить к дешифровке применением достаточно простой атаки, которая иллюстрируется картинкой:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Где кодированное изображение пингвина как бы ни фига не кодировано.

Вам надо выбирать шифратор следующим образом:

```
//алгоритм AES, мода сцепления CBC, режим выравнивания PKCS5
Cipher cipher=Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
```

Вторая проблема кодирование строки в байты. Чтобы код был портабельным надо явно указывать кодировку, а именно:

```
byte[] b=s.getBytes("UTF-8");
```

И отсюда же проистекает обратное кодирование из байтов в строку:

```
String s=new String(byteArray, "UTF-8");
time.setText(s);
```

Answer (score 0):

В цикле соберите строку, например, в `StringBuilder`, а после цикла уже вызывайте `setText()`.

```
StringBuilder text=new StringBuilder();
for (byte b : decriptedBytes){
    text.append((char) b);
}
time.setText(text.toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

Цикл поменяйте на такой цикл

```
String st = "";
for (byte b : decriptedBytes) st+=(char) b;
time.setText(st);
```